# Update Product Name Magento 2

Tags: magento, collections, magento2, updatemodel

i want to update some product Attributes e.g. Name, Description ...

what i did :

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$productFactory = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory');

$product = $productFactory->create();

$product->load($product->getIdBySku($sku));

if(!empty($product->getData('sku')))
{
    $product->setName('Test1234');
    $product->save();

}
```

No Errors are given but the Productname hasn't change.

Comment: Hi @Mr.Metz, Did You solved it, Can you provide a code snippet

Answer (score 1):

Do you even get to this part?

```
if(!empty($product->getData('sku')))
{
    $product->setName('Test1234');
    $product->save();
}
```

Either use debugger to check do you even go inside the `if` part, either you add some `var_dump` and `die` methods inside, so you can confirm that you get inside of the `if` part.

Btw, object manager should be initialized in the __construct method of the class (not directly as you initialized it).

Comment: hey, yeah it goes through the if part, i already debugged it. I also know that using the om isn't the best way, but i can't use constructor.

Comment: It is not updating for me